# Would it make sense to peel off paint from peeling bathtub

Tags: paint, bathtub

The paint in our tub has been developing air pockets under it for a while, and this morning a big chunk ripped off. [image]

As far as I can see, the layer underneath is undamaged except for the stains. Might it make sense to strip off the rest of the paint and live with the stains until I have the time and money for a better repair?

For those wondering how such a big chunk came off, last night I took off the non-slip mat which was suction-cupped to the tub and scrubbed the tub (non-abrasive cleaner, but rubbing pretty hard). This morning I stepped in for a shower, and the area where the mat had been detached.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if there is a correct answer. Stripping off all the paint would be a job, especially where it may be well adhered.  I think you would be well served to remove any loose areas as they develop until you are ready to do a complete refinish. When you do the refinish, then it will be necessary to strip all the paint and etch the original porcelain before proceeding. 
.

Comment: I have not seen that paint last well, on Victorian homes I have a guy "miracle Max" ok his name is max and he uses a process called miracle it takes a couple of days but looks new and holds up like having the tub reglassed (very expensive) you may look into having it done although it is possible the newer home processes are better than 20 years ago.+